# T-SQL : Error: 8114, Severity: 16, State: 5 Error converting data type varchar to float

Tags: t-sql

I'm debugging a java application which heavily uses t-sql stored procedure. Sometimes I get the post's title error. I think I've found the place where the error happens, but T-SQL isn't among my skills. Can anybody confirm that I'm right and suggest a solution please?

SQL Server 2005 stack trace show the following messages  :

```
set @prezzoUnitario2f = funcCtrlConvertToFloat] (@prezzoUnitario2)
IF @prezzoUnitario2f IS NULL OR cast(@prezzoUnitario2f as varchar) = '' OR @prezzoUnitario2f < 0
SET @defaultValue = NULL
IF ((select ISNUMERIC(@valueIn)) = 1)
```

> Error: 8114, Severity: 16, State: 5
>   Error converting data type varchar to float.

This is where the stored procedure calls the `funcCtrlConvertToFloat` function :

```
set @prezzoUnitario2f = [C4].[dbo].[funcCtrlConvertToFloat] (@prezzoUnitario2) --CONVERT(float,replace(@prezzoUnitario2,',','.'))
```

This is the `funcCtrlConvertToFloat` function :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[funcCtrlConvertToFloat]
(
@valueIn varchar(100)
)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @defaultValue float
DECLARE @returnValue float
SET @defaultValue = NULL
--SET @valueIn = ISNULL(@valueIn, 0)

IF ((select ISNUMERIC(@valueIn)) = 1)
BEGIN
SET @returnValue = CONVERT(float,replace(@valueIn ,',','.'))
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @returnValue = @defaultValue
END

RETURN @returnValue
END
```

As I've told I'm not a T-SQL programmer, so any hint would be appreciated

Comment: Can you check what kind of **input** gets sent to that function?? It appears to do some sanity checks - but for some reason, those aren't working all the time - knowing what values get passed into the function would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the following should solve your problem:

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[funcCtrlConvertToFloat] (
            @valueIn varchar(100)
    )
    RETURNS float
    AS BEGIN

    -- declare result variable and set a default value
    DECLARE @result float;
    SET @result = NULL;

    -- adjust @valueIn decimal separator
    SET @valueIn = REPLACE(@valueIn, ',', '.');

    -- if @valueIn is numeric set its value to the @result
    IF (ISNUMERIC(@valueIn) = 1)
    BEGIN
            SET @result = CONVERT(FLOAT, @valueIn);
    END

    RETURN @result;
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see your function is checking if the @valueIn is numeric before converting. Unfortunately `t-sql ISNUMERIC() function returns true for varchar values with group digit simbols (i.e. comma)`

For example;

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('12,345,678') returns true but fails in convertion
```

In your function please remove the grouping char from @valueIn before checking as follows

```
--New line to replace grouping char
SELECT @valueIn = REPLACE(@valueIn,',','')

IF ((SELECT ISNUMERIC(@valueIn)) = 1)
---Rest of the function
```

Hope this helps